# Adding nested entities to a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm using MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5 Code First.

I have the following entities:

```
public class File
{
    public string Album { get; set; }

    public string Genre { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public string GenreId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public string AlbumId { get; set; }
}
```

I try to add them to a database:

```
        private readonly List<File> _files = new List<File>();

        var genres = _files
            .Select(x => new Genre { GenreId = x.Genre })
            .GroupBy(x => x.GenreId)
            .Select(x => x.First())
            .ToList();

        foreach (var genre in genres)
        {
            var genreId = genre.GenreId;

            var albums = _files
                .Where(x => x.Genre == genreId)
                .Select(x => new Album { AlbumId = x.Album })
                .GroupBy(x => x.AlbumId)
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .ToList();

            genre.Albums = albums;

            _unitOfWork.GenreRepository.Insert(genre);
        }
```

And I get the following error:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Albums'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Albums'. The duplicate key value is (Ooz).
```

The statement has been terminated.

The data I try to add looks like the following:

```
--Tribal 
----Ooz 
--Goa Trance 
----Ooz 
----Transient Dawn 
--Progressive Trance 
----Ooz 
----Music Prostitute: The Remixes 
--Psy-Trance 
----Music Prostitute: The Remixes 
--Downtempo 
----Transient Dawn 
--Ambient 
----Transient Dawn
```

I see that I'm trying to add each album many times (because each album has many genres) but I don't know how to solve that issue.

Thanks for help!

Comment: _files is a List<File>. I index my mp3 file tags into it and then parse into Genres, Albums etc. I added it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the list of albums, try to get an album from the database before creating it.

Try this:

```
var albums = _files
            .Where(x => x.Genre == genreId)
            .Select(x => _yourDBContext.Albums.Where(album=>album.AlbumId == x.Album).FirstOrDefault() ?? 
                         new Album { AlbumId = x.Album })
            .GroupBy(x => x.AlbumId)
            .Select(x => x.First())
            .ToList();
```

The ?? is the null-coalescing operator, it chooses the second value if the first is null. I'm not sure, but hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing into `List<File>` just insert into database at that step.  Of course, you'll need to look to see if the genre exists, and if it does then insert files under that genre, if not then insert a new genre with the files already in the `List<Album> Albums`

Since you can do all of this in one context, entity will be very efficient for you.  What I mean is that entity will track whether things are in the database or not and you can just build the tree of genres and albums and call one save changes.

Comment: But how to check if Album exists or not? Please give me a simple example.

Comment: You can simply use <code>_yourDBContext.Albums.Where(album => album.AlbumId == "someId");</code> as you can see in my answer. Tell me if it helps you or not.

Comment: Mzn gave me an example that helped but I'm thinking of your suggestion... My model is quite complex and there are many many-to-many navigation properties between just 5 entities. I index mp3 tags one by one... How to do it without List<File>? Thanks!

Comment: matt-dot-net, I've got how to do it! That is awesome!